# change even on datetime input field does not track time

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, lightninginput, js

I am using a datetime input field in LWC:

```
   <lightning-input type="datetime" name="input5" label="ADate Time" value={avlue} min={minEndDate} max={maxEndDate} onchange={handleDateChange} required></lightning-input>
```

in JS:

```
handleDateChange(event){
  this.setDate = event.target.value;
  console.log(' this.setDate---> ' +  this.setDate);
  if(this.setDate != null){
    this.disableButton = false;
  }else{
    this.disableButton = true;
  }
}
```

When I wipe out the time value from the input , it does not trigger the handle change event. When the value in time field is removed I still the previous time in `this.setDate` variable.

How can I handle change to date AND Time field bot in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug with lightning-input. Fortunately, you can fix this easily by adding an onblur handler:

```
<lightning-input type="datetime" name="input5" label="ADate Time" value={value} min={minEndDate} max={maxEndDate}
    onchange={handleDateChange} onblur={report} required></lightning-input>
```

---

```
  report(event) {
    event.target.reportValidity();
    if(!event.target.validity.valid) {
      this.setDate = null;
      console.log(' this.setDate---> ' +  this.setDate);
    }
  }
```

[Demo](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/buxPsRjMtbfqqIt5NB46/src/app.js?p=stories).